# Joining on a timestamp within 30 seconds of each other?

Tags: sql, data-science, data-analysis, presto, sql-timestamp

I have a query where I am trying to join on a timestamp, but since there are not exact timestamps in one table and only every 30 seconds, can I join on that condition?

```
SELECT * FROM table loc
LEFT JOIN table dest ON loc.id = dest.id AND loc.timestamp = dest.timestamp
```

**Except the second ON portion of the join I want it to be if the loc.timesamp = dest.timestamp if they are within 30 seconds of each other**

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can express it as:

```
SELECT *
FROM table loc LEFT JOIN
     table dest
     ON loc.id = dest.id AND
        loc.timestamp >= dest.timestamp - INTERVAL '30' SECOND AND
        loc.timestamp <= dest.timestamp + INTERVAL '30' SECOND;
```

Answer (score 4):

Consider:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table loc
LEFT JOIN table dest 
    ON loc.id = dest.id 
    AND loc.timestamp 
        BETWEEN dest.timestamp - interval '30' second
        AND dest.timestamp + interval '30' second
```

While this will work; you need to consider the risk that multiple records would exist in the `dest` table with the joining interval. If this happens, then you would end up with duplicated `loc` records in the resultset. Depending on your data, this may or may not happen.